# How to use a javascript variable in scriptlet code.

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I have a variable v which contains a string type value at any point of time . Now i want to use these variable v in database connectivity code.. in my SQL query in Where clause, Something like this `"Where F_Name = "v"";` . But as the code is in javascript or `<script>` tags. how can i use it in scriptlets `<%%>` where my database connectivity code will go. The part of the code where i am declaring my var v is ::

```
dojo.connect(gridemp, "onRowDblClick", gridemp, function(){
                var items = gridemp.selection.getSelected();



            //  do something with the selected items
                dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
                    var v = gridemp.store.getValue(item,"ID");
```

Now once i get a selected value in v i want to use it in query. How to do this . ? Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Javascript plays at client side where scriptlet is serverside stuff,

You need to set the string to some hidden field and make a form post/ajax request to server where it processes the data from request